# Finding Jordan form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way to know the original matrix when given its Jordan form?

For example, the Jordan form of matrix $A$ is $\text{diag}(J_3(1), J_3(0))$, so I know that the $Pa(x) = x^3(x-1)^3$.

I need to find the jordan form of $A^2$ and $A^3$.

Comment: Generally it is not enough to know the Jordan form of a matrix, since it is simply a similarity transformation that connects them.  However if the Jordan form is a multiple of the identity, then the only possibility for the original is that same multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

The Jordan form of the Square of the Jordan form of $A$ is also the Jordan form of $A^2$ (why?)

Comment: why? i don't think i understand